# Flask app deployed on PythonAnywhere with Machine Learning model not responding

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, pythonanywhere, imageai

I am new to PythonAnywhere and facing an issue while deploying my Flask app. The app works fine on my local PC, but I encountered problems when deploying it to PythonAnywhere. Specifically, when I send a POST request with a key "image" and upload an image in JPEG format, the request takes an unusually long time and eventually results in an error message saying "Something went wrong". Same goes with sending a POST request in /live_detect. Surprisingly, there are no relevant error messages in the error logs.

POST request = https://tomatosrapp.pythonanywhere.com/detect

```
app = Flask("Tomatect")
CORS(app)

model_path = "model.pt"
json_path = "json/detection_config.json"

prediction = CustomObjectDetection()
prediction.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
prediction.setModelPath(model_path)
prediction.setJsonPath(json_path)
prediction.loadModel()

video_detector = CustomVideoObjectDetection()
video_detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
video_detector.setModelPath(model_path)
video_detector.setJsonPath(json_path)
video_detector.loadModel()

@app.route("/detect", methods=["POST"])
def detect():
    if "image" not in request.files:
        return jsonify({"error": "No image uploaded"}), 400

    image = request.files["image"]
    #image.save(image.filename)

    detections = prediction.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=image,
                                                   output_image_path=None)

    results = []
    for detection in detections:
        result = {
            "name": detection["name"],
            "percentage_probability": detection["percentage_probability"],
            "box_points": detection["box_points"]
        }
        results.append(result)

    return jsonify(results), 200

@app.route("/live_detect", methods=["POST"])
def live_detect():
    if "video" not in request.files:
        return jsonify({"error": "No video uploaded"}), 400

    video = request.files["video"]
    video.save(video.filename)

    def forFrame(frame_number, output_array, output_count):
        results = []
        for detection in output_array:
            result = {
                "name": detection["name"],
                "percentage_probability": detection["percentage_probability"]
            }
            results.append(result)

        print(results) 

    video_detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(input_file_path=video.filename,
                                          frames_per_second=20,
                                          frame_detection_interval=1,
                                          per_frame_function=forFrame,
                                          output_file_path="output_video.avi",
                                          minimum_percentage_probability=30)

    return "Live detection completed"
```

Btw, I have upgraded my PythonAnywhere account to the 2000 ms CPU and 10GB disk quota. Also, model.pt file is 235MB if it matters.

I have attempted to save the image to a temporary file as a potential solution, but the issue remains unresolved. Can PythonAnywhere effectively handle this type of project?

Comment: I'd suggest adding the request you are actually sending and how, so someone can emulate what you are doing. I'm assuming the issue is the call for `detectObjectsFromImage`?

Comment: Added now: https://tomatosrapp.pythonanywhere.com/detect.

I am not really sure if the issue is the call for detectObjectsFromImage since there's no errors in logs and it works perfectly in my local pc.

Comment: could be that files are organized on PythonAnywhere in a different structure (folder hierarchy) from your local machine. Based on that, try  ```app = Flask(__name__)``` instead of your current ```app = Flask("Tomatect")```. See [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/why-do-we-pass-name-to-the-flask-class) for an explanation

Comment: I did that but it didn't resolve the issue. The directory and folder hierarchy is correct. I think the issue is that PythonAnywhere couldn't handle some machine learning models based on this page: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/MachineLearningInWebsiteCode/

Answer (score 3):

I just resolved the issue by setting the number of threads

```
import torch
torch.set_num_threads(1)
```